# How to change the color of a UIBezierPath after added on View in Swift?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, swift2

I'm working on a project that draws shapes on view. The `UIBezierPath` used to create the shapes and added in view.

```
var frame: CGRect = bounds
var strokeColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(frame.minX + floor((frame.width - 79) * 0.50000 + 0.5), frame.minY + floor((frame.height - 79) * 0.50000 + 0.5), 79, 79))
UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
strokeColor.setStroke()
ovalPath.lineWidth = 1.5
ovalPath.stroke()
```

My question is: **How can I change the color of the shape by clicking on it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is in a `drawRect` method? Just update `strokeColor` and then call `setNeedsDisplay()` on the view which will trigger the calling of `drawRect` again.

Personally, I'd put `strokeColor` in a property with a `didSet`, rather than a local variable of the `drawRect` method. Then, when I update `strokeColor`, it automatically triggers the redrawing of the view:

```
var strokeColor: UIColor? {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}
```

Comment: How I use for change color after add on view?

Comment: Well, I assume you'd keep a reference to this custom view, say `customView`. Then you'd do something like: `customView.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()` or what have you.